# cryptic clue: mammal sounds like relative consumer (8)

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords, crossword-clues

While solving [this cryptic](http://www.puzzlechoice.com/pc2/Cryptic22x.html) I figured out the answer to 1-across (mammal sounds like relative consumer) without solving the [subsidiary indication](http://enigma.puzzlers.org/guide/cryptics1). (I used down constraints and the standard part of the clue to guess the right answer.) After confirming my answer in the solution (warning: spoiler) [here](http://www.puzzlechoice.com/pc2/Cryptic22solx.html), I am even more baffled as to how the subsidiary was supposed to work. Please help!

Comment: The link to the crossword gives 403 Forbidden. Possibly it only works for people who are logged into the site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe

> "sounds like relative" refers to *ant* (aunt), so the clue is "ant consumer," which is an **AARDVARK** by ddef.

Comment: Sounds plausible. I think the wordplay would make a lot more sense if the actual answer was rot13(nagrngre), though...

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why there would be a homophone in a double definition clue, but I guess that’s just what the clue writer wanted to do

Comment: Hm, that seems like the right answer, but it's also *completely invalid* as wordplay according to most standards. You can't do some word manipulation to something and then use it in part of a definition. (Synonymizing always has to be on the "lowest level" of the parse tree.)

Comment: @Deusovi I recognize that, but there just doesn’t seem to be any other interpretation that gives the correct answer. My first thought was to find a homophone of the word that also meant “relative consumer,” but I couldn’t think of anything. I think the clue writer was trying to be clever and didn’t want to stick with traditional cryptic clue standards

Answer (score 6):

I see this as being

> relative = aunt = (sounds like) ant and consumer = eater giving anteater which is an alternative name for aardvark.

Interestingly enough, this would actually fit as it is and is what I would have put down on first seeing the puzzle. This would have given me a lot of headaches with 2,3 and 4 down later!

Comment: I'd expect that wordplay should always resolve to *the solution*, not to something that means the same thing. I've never seen wordplay that resolves to a *definition* rather than the actual solution word(s). This clue seems unfair to me, and I'm not surprised at OP's bafflement.

Comment: Exactly why I would have (incorrectly) entered rot13(nagrngre) as the answer :)